# Describing the force you see on a scale

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I recently came across a multiple-choice question that is asking me to describe the force displayed by a scale when a person stands on it (no acceleration). The question gives the following options:

**A.** The weight force on the person

**B.** The normal force

**C.** The reaction force on the normal force

**D.** The reaction force on the weight force

I thought that it would simply be B, since when the system is not accelerating, the weight force would equal the normal force.

However, the answer is C. What does "the reaction force on the normal force" exactly mean, and why is this the displayed force?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Duplicate? [Which force does a weighing scale measure?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276642/which-force-does-a-weighing-scale-measure/276661#276661)

Comment: I think the main problem I have is understanding how the reaction force of the normal force is different to the normal force itself. Would it just be the direction of the force that changes, or does it have to do with something else?

Comment: Normal force = force on person due to pan and the reaction to the normal force is the force on pan due to person - Newton's third law.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this question some more, I think that this question really has to do with understanding / applying Newton's third law and considering force-pairs.

If we are considering force pairs (see diagram below), we would have $F_{Mg}$ acting on the Earth and $F'_{Mg}$ acting on the object. We would have something similar for the normal force $F_N$ acting on the object and $F'_N$ acting on the scale. Therefore, $F'_N$, the reaction force of the normal force, would be the force that describes the weight of the object on the scale.

[image: Diagram showing force pairs for object on scale]